# What is needed to get my custom ZipList applicative instance to compile?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Here is my custom List class used to create a custom ZipList class. I want to create a ZipList' applicative instance.

```
import Control.Applicative

data List a =
  Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor List where
  fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f (Cons (head' xs) (tail' xs)))
  fmap _ Nil = Nil

instance Applicative List where
  pure x = Cons x Nil
  (<*>) fs xs = Cons (head' fs $ head' xs) ((<*>) (tail' fs) (tail' xs))

head' :: List a -> a
head' (Cons a _) = a

tail' :: List a -> List a
tail' (Cons _ l) = l

take' :: Int -> List a -> List a
take' 0 _ = Nil
take' _ Nil = Nil
take' i xs = Cons (head' xs) (take' (i-1) (tail' xs))

newtype ZipList' a =
  ZipList' (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor ZipList' where
  fmap f (ZipList' xs) = ZipList' $ fmap f xs

instance Applicative ZipList' where
  pure x = ZipList' (Cons x Nil)
  (<*>) fs xs = ZipList' (go fs xs)
    where go gs ys = Cons (head' gs $ head' ys) (go (tail' gs) (tail' ys))
          go Nil _ = Nil
          go _ Nil = Nil
```

The error I am getting is:

```
chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:30: Couldn't match expected type ‘List (r0 -> b)’ …
                with actual type ‘ZipList' (a -> b)’
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: ZipList' a
        (bound at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:12)
      fs :: ZipList' (a -> b)
        (bound at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:9)
      (<*>) :: ZipList' (a -> b) -> ZipList' a -> ZipList' b
        (bound at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:3)
    In the first argument of ‘go’, namely ‘fs’
    In the first argument of ‘ZipList'’, namely ‘(go fs xs)’
chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:33: Couldn't match expected type ‘List r0’ …
                with actual type ‘ZipList' a’
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: ZipList' a
        (bound at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:12)
      fs :: ZipList' (a -> b)
        (bound at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:9)
      (<*>) :: ZipList' (a -> b) -> ZipList' a -> ZipList' b
        (bound at /Users/ebs/code/haskell/book/chap17/ZipList_applicative.hs:38:3)
    In the second argument of ‘go’, namely ‘xs’
    In the first argument of ‘ZipList'’, namely ‘(go fs xs)’
Compilation failed.
```

It says that it expects a List (r0 -> b) type from go, not ZipList'. I do not get why, go returns a List, not a ZipList'...

Comment: Your `fmap` is more complicated than it needs to be; `fmap (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)`. The pattern matching on the next call takes care of breaking down `xs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `go` takes `ZipList` as input, but in `(<*>) fs xs` `xs` and `fs` are `ZipList'`s. You should unwrap the newtype:

```
ZipList' fs <*> ZipList' xs = ZipList' (go fs xs)
```

Also, your `go` is wrong. It fails with a runtime error whenever the program evaluates an empty list in either arguments, because the `go gs ys` case matches everything, and the cases after it are unreachable. You should instead do something like this:

```
go (Cons f fs) (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (go fs xs)
go _ _ = Nil
```

As a general rule, you should avoid `head`, `tail`, and other partial functions (i. e. functions that possibly throw exceptions). Pattern matching on `Cons x xs` binds both the head and the tail, so there isn't much use for `head` and `tail` thereafter. It's very rare that the use of partial functions is truly justified.